# Javascript after looping around a Google analytics api call, how do I display multiple results?

Tags: javascript, loops

After following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js) I have made a success call to retrieve analytic data from Google. I then loop round it using different view IDs.  I can only manage to display one result. Here is my code:

```
function queryData() {

     var ids = [["900846", "/abc"], ["7532846", "/blog/abc/"]];

     ids.forEach(function (entry) {
         gapi.client.request({
             path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
             root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
             method: 'POST',
             body: {
                 reportRequests: [{
                     viewId: entry[0],
                     dateRanges: [{
                         startDate: '7daysAgo',
                         endDate: 'today'
                     }],
                     metrics: [{
                         expression: "ga:uniquePageviews",
                     },
                     ],
                     dimensionFilterClauses: [{

                         filters: [{

                             dimension_name: 'ga:pagePath',
                             operator: 'EXACT',
                             expressions: [entry[1]]
                         }]
                     }]

                 }]
             }
         }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
     })
 }


 function displayResults(response) {
     var result = response.result;
     document.getElementById('query-output').value = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
 }
```

This just displays one result, when in the array above there are two.  Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your #query-output value is getting reassigned each time the request finishes. Instead of that, output it to the console to check if there are multiple values. If there are, try this instead:

```
document.getElementById('query-output').value += JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you it was += operator  I was looking for - life saver! new to JS and had me puzzled for hours trying all sorts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Promise.all` to determine when all of the calls are complete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const results = ids.map(function (entry) {
  return gapi.client.request({
    ...
  })
})
Promise.all(results).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
```

You'll have to refactor your `displayResults` method to handle the array it returns.

Comment: Thank you very much for this method.  I will try this next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you accumulate the result in the displayResults function?

Something like

```
var result;
function displayResults(response){
    result = result + response.result;
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
}
```

not sure what you're doing with the string, maybe you need to concatenate it in another way, but the general idea should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I was just missing += operator but the same principle so thanks!